# Google Cloud Speech Streaming API with FLAC

Tags: google-cloud-speech

For using Google Cloud Speech API via the streaming API([Performing Streaming Speech Recognition on an Audio Stream](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize#performing_streaming_speech_recognition_on_an_audio_stream)) with sox, how to configure it to run with FLAC?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? **Streaming** speech recognition (in contrast to synchronous and asynchronous) is not meant to be done on audio files but rather on a stream incoming via microphone. I cannot see where flac and sox fit here.

Comment: With Dialog flow the recommended audio encoding was FLAC. What I'm looking for is to optimize the streaming audio encoding.

Comment: There's no reference of streaming audio in Dialogflow, the examples in [documentation on detecting intent from audio](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/detect-intent-audio#detect_intent) use audio files. Can you be more specific? Can you describe your implementation in more detail?

Comment: In the link above, section "Performing Streaming Speech Recognition on an Audio Stream" has the audio streaming from microphone sample.(note that I'm using the NodeJS sample)

Comment: Ok, I had to educate myself a bit, now I see how I was wrong. The problem is, I cannot see what the equivalent of 'node-record-lpcm16' for flac is. Since you only want to work with node, I think you should edit your question to address this more directly, i.e. how can you record flac in node.